# check MD5 checksums from md5 file in Windows

Tags: windows-command-prompt, md5, certutil

Hopefully a simple question, does a simple Windows command line equivalent to `md5sum --check [files.md5]` exist? Alternatively, something I can script as a batch file.

I can generate the hashes file fine, but it's the check at the destination, comparing with the md5 file that's proving tricky. Bonus points if it's possible to run in a batch file rather than PowerShell (need to try and create something relatively simple for a user to run routinely).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Powershell is your friend.
You could run this with a CMD/BAT wrapper to just run the script for them

```
clear-host
$sourcemd5 = get-content C:\temp\cp053854.md5

cd C:\Temp
foreach ($datarow in $sourcemd5){
    # try this to replace mutli spaces with single. uses regex
    $datarow = $($datarow -replace '\s+', ' ')
    $dlhash = $null
    $currentFileHash = $null
    $currentFileName = $null
    #use the first (0) token found (hash value)
    $currentFileHash = ($datarow.Split(" "))[0]
    #use the second (1) token found (filename value)
    $currentFileName = ($datarow.Split(" "))[1]
    #$currentFileName check if has leading asterisk*.
    if ($currentFileName -match "\*"){
        #remove it
        $currentFileName = $currentFileName.Trim("\*")
    }
    
    # Generate an MD5 of the filesystem file
    $dlhash = get-filehash $currentFileName -Algorithm MD5
    #set the generated hash value as string for comparison to the text file.
    [string]$dlhashstr = $dlhash.Hash
    write-output "checking file                   [$currentfileName]"
    write-output "downloaded file hash            [$dlhashstr]"
    write-output "hash value should be            [$currentFileHash]"
    #perform a case insensitive comparison if MD5file uses caps or not. 
    if ($dlhashstr -eq $currentFileHash){
    write-output "File hashes correctly match up  [$currentFileName]"
    }else{
    Write-Warning "MD5 checksum mismatch  [$currentFileName]"
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that just provide the hash for <filename>?
I was after the equivalent of ```md5sum --check <filename>``` where it confirms the list of hashes in 'filename' match the files in that directory.

Comment: Edited after revising my original answer, hope this helps